# Google Maps API - How to get only districts names of city?

Tags: google-maps

I would like to create a two-steps form using Google Maps API. At first, the user would like to select a city. Then, in next step, I want to generate a select list with district names of city (which was specified in first step).

I know how to create an autocomplete input with cities but I can't find any informations about districts. Is it possible using Google Maps API?